# Удалить id из input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input со списком id через запятую. Нужно при клике по кнопке, удалить одно из значений.

```html
<input type="text" name="id" value="11879,16806,12552">

<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="11879">Удалить 11879</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="16806">Удалить 16806</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="12552">Удалить 12552</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x32d4o19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-primary.del').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let id = e.target.dataset.id,
    input = document.querySelector('input[name="id"]'),
    arr = input.value.split(','),
    index = arr.indexOf(id);

  if (~index)
    arr.splice(index, 1);

  input.value = arr.join(',');
}));
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id" value="11879,16806,12552">

<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="11879">Удалить 11879</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="16806">Удалить 16806</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary del" data-id="12552">Удалить 12552</div>
```